# Is There A Way To Include Data With Http/Guzzle Response In Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

So I am trying to return `User` data with login request. I am using guzzle and I do not know how to attach data to response.

Here is the login method

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        try {
            $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    ]
                    ]);


                    return $response->getBody();
                } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
                    if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                        return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
                    } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                        return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

I would like to do something like this

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->username)->get();

$token = $response->getBody();

return response()->json($token, $user);
```

However when I try this I get error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Currently I am having to make separate request after access token to return the user data thus I would like for it to happen at the same time....

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of json method can be an array:

```
return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'user' => $user ]);
```

Comment: thank you for the help. For some reason `$token` is returning empty object. Any ideas?

Comment: I was recommended this [discusstion](https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d) and it worked. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was recommended the following [discussion](https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d) and it solved my issue. here is the final code

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        try {
            $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    ]
                    ]);

                    $token = $response->getBody();

                    $data = json_decode($token, true);

                    $user = User::where('email', $request->username)->with('role.rules')->get();

                    $rules = $user->pluck('role')->collapse()->pluck('rules');

                    $rules->put('access_token', $data['access_token']);

                    return response()->json($rules);
                } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
                    if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                        return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
                    } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                        return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```